# Debugger Settings Change Between Visual Studio Instances

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I having the most annoying problem with Visual Studio 2012 settings. Every time I close and re-open Visual Studio I find the Just My Code debugger setting disabled. No matter how many times I enable it, it is always disabled the next time I open the IDE.

Any idea how this could be occurring? All the other settings seem to persist well. It's only the Just My Code setting that's changing.

Comment: Disable add-ins one by one to find the troublemaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.

I have the .NET Reflector Plug-In installed in Visual Studio and it apparently doesn't like "Just My Code" so it disables it on start up.